# Run kaminari specs

Tags: ruby, kaminari

this is probably a stupid question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I'd like to contribute to [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), so I forked the repo, `bundle`'d it, and now I would like to run the specs to ensure all's green. But I can't seem to make it work :

```
bin/rake spec                                                                                                                                                        

/Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby -S rspec spec/config/config_spec.rb spec/helpers/action_view_extension_spec.rb spec/helpers/helpers_spec.rb spec/helpers/sinatra_helpers_spec.rb spec/helpers/tags_spec.rb spec/models/active_record/active_record_relation_methods_spec.rb spec/models/active_record/default_per_page_spec.rb spec/models/active_record/scopes_spec.rb spec/models/array_spec.rb spec/models/data_mapper/data_mapper_spec.rb spec/models/mongo_mapper/mongo_mapper_spec.rb spec/models/mongoid/mongoid_spec.rb spec/requests/users_spec.rb
warning: no framework detected.
would you check out if your Gemfile appropriately configured?
---- e.g. ----
when Rails:
    gem 'kaminari'

when Sinatra/Padrino:
    gem 'kaminari', :require => 'kaminari/sinatra'

when Grape:
    gem 'kaminari', :require => 'kaminari/grape'

/Users/Ksoltysiak/Documents/Repositories/kaminari/spec/models/array_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Kaminari::PaginatableArray (NameError)
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
/Users/Ksoltysiak/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby -S rspec spec/config/config_spec.rb spec/helpers/action_view_extension_spec.rb spec/helpers/helpers_spec.rb spec/helpers/sinatra_helpers_spec.rb spec/helpers/tags_spec.rb spec/models/active_record/active_record_relation_methods_spec.rb spec/models/active_record/default_per_page_spec.rb spec/models/active_record/scopes_spec.rb spec/models/array_spec.rb spec/models/data_mapper/data_mapper_spec.rb spec/models/mongo_mapper/mongo_mapper_spec.rb spec/models/mongoid/mongoid_spec.rb spec/requests/users_spec.rb failed
```

I tried to bypass bundler, but then I got gems issues with versions and stuff. So what am I missing here ? I don't find anything on the wiki or the issues, or even here about this.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently made series of changes on Kaminari tests. https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/compare/b61db76...1f8389ae

As a result of this big refactoring, now the tests can be run separately per each ORM library, for example like this:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=gemfiles/active_record_32.gemfile bundle exec rake spec
```

To run all tests at once, you should invoke `spec:all` task:

```
bundle exec rake spec:all
```

I'm aware that this is a bit unusual. At least it apparently needs to be documented. I'll do so till the next stable release.

Or if you have any better solution, please tell me.